# How do I append multiple CSS Classes to winjs listview

Tags: winjs

I have a very simple list view that pulls back from a dynamic data source`

```
<div id="crCarouselGrid" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="crCarouselGridItemImg" style="margin:0 auto !important; width:175px; " data-win-bind="className:asset_class"></div>
    <div class="crCarouselGridItemTitle" data-win-bind="textContent: label"></div>  
</div>  `
```

I need to add additional classes beyond just my grid structure classes - but it looks they are getting stripped out when modifying the className: with asset_name class.

I find it odd winJS can't handle an append of multiple class structures in this way as it is quite common. Any ideas how this might be done? Outside of me adding a bunch of inline style stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really digging into it, a few choices come to mind, none of them tested, or especially satisfying for that matter:

- Try using a Binding initializer (or possibly converter) to build the functionality you need to append a class instead of replace
- Instead of `class="crCarouselGridItemImg"` a workaround would be to use a data attribute like `data-class="crCarouselGridItemImg"`, and then changing your CSS from `.crCarouselGridItemImg { ... }` to `[data-class=crCarouselGridItemImg] { ... }`
- Instead of binding the CSS class declaratively, do it in `done`:

  - `WinJS.Binding.processAll(...).done( /* in here */ );`

Comment: For now I went with the inline style, but I think your first to answers would have worked with a little bit more extra code. I like the usage of a new data-class as we tend to use custom data attributes for quite a few things.

Comment: As it turns out, yesterday I needed to solve this exact problem.  I went with my second suggestion (`data-` attribute) and it worked nicely with very minimal changes to the code that existed before the requirement of binding an additional CSS class.